# "You have gone over your usage limits" Firebase Realtime Database Limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time-data

[image]

I publish my app on play store before 2 month and today I get Firebase limits error on Firebase Real-Time database. What do i do now ?

Comment: How about you contact Firebase?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not something anyone but Firebase support can assist with.

Answer (score 1):

You have gone over the limits of the free [Spark plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for the Realtime Database.

You should either upgrade to the [Blaze plan](https://Blaze%20plan) or, if possible, adapt your DB size and usage to be under the free limits, i.e. remove some data and decrease the daily usage (GB downloaded and possibly simultaneous connections). See the [doc item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) for more details.